# Internal Server Error while doing post request in flask using nginx and uwsgi

Tags: python, linux, nginx, flask, uwsgi

**I am using this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04)**

**Background**: I am using `flask` post API to activate selenium to extract information and send them to website. This work perfectly when I don't apply `nginx` configuration and just run the below code on server (as in local machine using port 5000).

**Problem**: when I try to deploy the flask application by mean of `nginx` and `uwsgi` and following the indication of this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) I get an **internal server error** whenever I do the POST request `http://my_domain/find_data`.

Below I'll show part of my code.

```
from app import app
if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

The `app.py` code (it manages the POST request `http://my_domain/find_data`) is:

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory, stream_with_context, request, Response
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse
from flask_cors import CORS #comment this on deployment
from data_finder import DataFinder
from time import sleep
from contextlib import closing
import requests
import json 
from flask import jsonify
from flask import jsonify, make_response

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='frontend/build')
CORS(app) #comment this on deployment
api = Api(app)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, 'index.html')

@app.route("/find_data", methods = ['POST'])
def FindData():
    person = request.get_json()['person']
    print(person)
    results = {}
    data_finder = DataFinder()


    results['Spokeo'] = list(data_finder.get_spokeo_data(person))
    results['White Pages'] = list(data_finder.get_whitepages_data(person).keys())

    return make_response(jsonify(results), 200)
```

My `project.ini` file is this:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = myproject.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

Lastly my `nginx` configuration file is

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_domain www.my_domain;


    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/help/data-finder/privaseame_web_app/myproject.sock;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 900;
        proxy_read_timeout 1800;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
        proxy_send_timeout 1800;
        send_timeout 1800;
    }

    client_header_timeout 900s;
    client_body_timeout 900s;
    keepalive_timeout 900s;
    send_timeout 900s;
}
```

I am using digital ocean linux droplet Ubuntu 18-0.4 LTS
Running python3.10.6
I used below stack overflow links but information on them is not sufficient

[Guide1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62543174/flask-app-on-nginx-time-out-after-1-minute)
[Guide2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209978/serving-a-front-end-created-with-create-react-app-with-flask)

If I miss any information please let me know I will provide.

Thanks for your insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Pay attention at the names of the file!

I have followed [the same tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04).

From your answer are not clear names of the different files that you have created.
I suggest you to follow exactly [the tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) and in particular the names schema (for the files) that it suggests.
I try to give you some advices.

- The name of your file:

```
from app import app
if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

must be `uwsgi.py` because in the file `project.ini` you use the option:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app
```

- The name of your file:

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory, stream_with_context, request, Response
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse
from flask_cors import CORS #comment this on deployment
from data_finder import DataFinder
from time import sleep
from contextlib import closing
import requests
import json 
from flask import jsonify
from flask import jsonify, make_response

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='frontend/build')
CORS(app) #comment this on deployment
api = Api(app)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, 'index.html')

@app.route("/find_data", methods = ['POST'])
def FindData():
    person = request.get_json()['person']
    print(person)
    results = {}
    data_finder = DataFinder()


    results['Spokeo'] = list(data_finder.get_spokeo_data(person))
    results['White Pages'] = list(data_finder.get_whitepages_data(person).keys())

    return make_response(jsonify(results), 200)
```

must be `app.py` because in the file `uwsgi.py` you use the instruction:
`from app import app`

- Make sure you have created the Unix socket file `myproject.sock` in the same folder that contains `app.py` and `uwsgi.py`.
  In fact in the file `project.ini` you are using the option:

```
socket = myproject.sock
```

To create this socket and give it the right permission you can use the following Python script:

```
import socket as s
import pwd
import grp
import os

path = './myproject.sock'

# create the `Unix Domain Socket`
sock = s.socket(s.AF_UNIX)
sock.bind(path)

# set user and group for the Unix Domain Socket created (www is the same user of NGINX)
uid = pwd.getpwnam("www").pw_uid
gid = grp.getgrnam("www").gr_gid

os.chown(path, uid, gid)
os.chmod(path, 0o660)
```

Save previous program in the folder where you have to create the Unix Domain Socket (see the instruction `path = './myproject.sock'`).
May be it exists other ways to create a Unix Socket Domain file, but I used the previous Python program in my **flask/uwsgi** application.

I hope that these advises are useful for you.

Comment: This answer works as I change the names of files and follow exactly.

Comment: I accepted answer pardon me for being late frankfalse