# Ubuntu flask app looks like not working because trying to find file in part of code that was deleted

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, flask, uwsgi

Hello I'm trying to run my flask app on ubuntu server (digital ocean droplet) but I encounter some weird error.
The error message says that the path of file is incorrect but I have changed this file and now it doesn't contains any paths so I'd know why I see this error.

Here is the error message:

```
 File "/var/www/html/cancel-the-cancer/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 107, in view
    return current_app.ensure_sync(self.dispatch_request)(**kwargs)
  File "/var/www/html/cancel-the-cancer/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 582, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/html/cancel-the-cancer/Resources/predict.py", line 10, in post
    img = img.resize((256, 256))
  File "/var/www/html/cancel-the-cancer/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 3002, in save
    dst = open(dst, "wb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './images/ISIC_0029612.jpg.jpg'
```

Here is `predic.py` file:

```
import numpy as np
from flask_restful import Resource, request
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image

class Predict(Resource):
    def post(self):
        file = request.files['image']
        img = Image.open(file.stream)
        img = img.resize((256, 256))
        img = np.array(img)
        img = img / 255.0
        img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
        loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('../model/vgg19_92%_93%')
        prediction = loaded_model.predict(img)[0][0]
        return {"result": float(prediction)}
```

Here is `app.py` file:

```
import flask_restful
from flask_cors import CORS

from flask_cors import CORS
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api

from Resources.predict import Predict

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'zwolnienizteorii44893'
api = Api(app)
cors = CORS(app)

api.add_resource(Predict, '/predict')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

I have also try the same application on my personal computer with windows 11 and on win it works well and returns predict but on ubuntu as api response i receive internal server error.

im trying

`sudo systemctl restart uwsgi`

`sudo systemctl restart nginx`

`sudo systemctl reload uwsgi`

`sudo systemctl reload nginx`

Comment: Try to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74078549/internal-server-error-while-doing-post-request-in-flask-using-nginx-and-uwsgi) and [its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74078549/internal-server-error-while-doing-post-request-in-flask-using-nginx-and-uwsgi/74179158#74179158). There you can find the link for a tutorial and in the post some other details about your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello i finally fix my issues with my code.
First i crate a completly new droplet and followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-22-04)

I'm folowing the code so i got the same names as in tutrial also path like this `../model/vgg_19_92%_93%` casusing an error so i must change it to `home/kremobil/cancelthecancer/model/vgg_19_92%_93%`

here is files i changed or crated

`cancelthecancer.py` previously `app.py`:

```
import flask_restful
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api

from Resources.predict import Predict

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'zwolnienizteorii44893'
api = Api(app)
cors = CORS(app)

api.add_resource(Predict, '/predict')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

here is `predict.py`:

```
import numpy as np
from flask_restful import Resource, request
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image

class Predict(Resource):
    def post(self):
        file = request.files['image']
        img = Image.open(file.stream)
        img = img.resize((256, 256))
        img = np.array(img)
        img = img / 255.0
        img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
        loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/home/kremobil/cancelthecancer/model/vgg19_92%_93%')
        prediction = loaded_model.predict(img)[0][0]
        return {"result": float(prediction)}
```

and here is new crated `wsgi.py` like in tutorial:

```
from cancelthecancer import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```